# Missing library at runtime with pyinstaller (libgcc_s.so.1)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a python program on Linux using PyInstaller. At runtime on the guest machine, I'm able to run the program but at some point, it crashes with the following error:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

What can I change in my packaging script in order to not get this issue?